# C# match substring with optional parameters

Tags: c#, regex, collections, match

I want to match this:

```
01+WhATEver 02+0.1 03+12.1\r\n
```

or this

```
01+WhATEver 02+0.1\r\n
```

appearing like this in the string I am parsing in any order

```
01+WhATEver 02+0.1 03+12.1\r\n01+WhATEver 02+0.1 03+12.1\r\n01+WhATEver 02+0.1 03+12.1\r\n
```

With 01-02 being mandatory and 03 being an optional parameter. An index looks like "01+" and can be followed by a minus sign like this.

```
01+WhATEver 02+-0.1\r\n
```

I am able to parse the mandatory indexes and variables but not including the optional one... since it will not match if it is missing.

```
01\\+\\s*(?<1>[.0-9A-Za-z]*)\\s*02\\+\\s*(?<2>[.0-9]*)\\s*03\\+\\s*(?<3>[.0-9]*)\\s*
```

What I need is a regex that will match with either 01-02 indexes or 01-03 out of a string containing many such substrings.

Comment: why do you need to do it all with 1 regex?

Comment: cb88, and just think, your team mate will read this regex.

Comment: @SamIam I'm working with existing code that works already except for the case where that optional paremeter occurs. Also I am the team mate reading this... I didn't write it. Personally I wouldn't have even used regexs :/ that is just how it is going to be. Also this is a simplified example :P

Comment: can you provide a list of valid inputs..this would let us understand your problem..your question in this form doesn't make any sense

Comment: The problem is that I can't match both the mandatory paremeters and the optional one when it occurs with the same regex which I do need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just make that group optional? Like this:

```
"01\\+\\s*(?<1>[.0-9A-Za-z]*)\\s*02\\+\\s*(?<2>[.0-9]*)(\\s*03\\+\\s*(?<3>[.0-9]*)\\s*)?"
                                                       ^                              ^^
```

(I underlined the characters that I added to the regex.)

Comment: I believe you are correct here however I need to investigate futher... but I think the problem is now in how I am handling the collection after I have matched the string.

Comment: This does match correctly however the number of groups in the match always includes the optional group even if it wasn't part of the string. So that makes determineing to parse it or not problematic.

Comment: You were correct I was able to detect that I had captured the group by match.groups[index].captures.count .